# Floating Health Bar Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: unity, c#

Currently working on an overhead display of the health bar and ran into this problem and I cannot seem to figure out why its not working correctly. When the player has less than `entity.health.max` the scale is set to 0 instead of the calculated percent.

Code:

```
private void SetHealth(int amount)
{
  currentHealth = amount;
  float displayedHealth = currentHealth / entity.health.max;
  healthBar.transform.localScale = new Vector3(displayedHealth, 1, 1);
}
```

I also tried the following with the same results

```
float displayedHealth = Mathf.Lerp(0, 1, currentHealth / entity.health.max);
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to cast both `int` as `float`

`float displayedHealth = (float)currentHealth / (float)entity.health.max;`

Comment: Casting just one term should be sufficient. `int / int` division in C# truncates, but `float / int` and `int / float` implicitly casts the mismatched integer into a float for you.